# Field validation show null pointer exception even if is not empty

Tags: android

I have trying to check if the edittext is empty or not. If is empty simply warn the user to put something in it. The problem is if I leave the field empty the app crash. If I put something in the field the app crash. Both time same error:

```
01-08 09:34:34.989: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 09:34:34.989: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 09:34:34.989: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at com.res.Reservation$3.onClick(Reservation.java:108)
```

This is the code

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(editText1.getText().toString().length()==0)  
            {           
                editText1.setError( "Please enter your name!" );  
            }  
            else if(editText3.getText().toString().length()==0)  
            {           
                editText3.setError( "Please enter phone number in format 1234567890" ); 
            }
            else if(editText2.getText().toString().length() == 0)  
            {           
                editText2.setError( "Please enter your Email" );
            }
            else if(datePicker.getText().toString().length()==0)  
            {           
                datePicker.setError( "Please choose date and time" );  
            }
            else if(editText5.getText().toString().length()==0)  
            {           
                editText5.setError( "Please enter number of people" );  
            }
            else
            {  
                Intent intent = new Intent(Reservation.this, TableReservation.class);
                String Name = editText1.getText().toString();
                String Email = editText2.getText().toString();
                String Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
                String Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
                String DateTime = datePicker.getText().toString();
                String numberOfPeople = editText5.getText().toString();


                intent.putExtra("Name", editText1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Email", editText2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Phone", editText3.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Comment", editText4.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("DateTime", datePicker.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("numberOfPeople", editText5.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("rest_id", getIntent().getStringExtra("rest_id").toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Line 108 is

```
   else if(editText5.getText().toString().length()==0)  
   {           
        editText5.setError( "Please enter number of people" );  
   }
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Post the code where you initialize the **editText5**

Comment: Probably deleted by mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

editText5 is null. Make sure you have initialized it

Comment: Yep, I must deleted it by mistake. That was the error. Thank's!